# Hive: Is it possible to use regexp_extract on a struct field? (NullPointerException)

Tags: json, regex, hive, amazon-dynamodb

I loaded a dynamodb full of twitter information (json format) into hive. The format from the json file looks like this:

```
{"id":{"s":"894643473017561088"},"sentiment":{"s":"neutral"},"subjectivity":{"s":"0.0"},"username":{"s":"Jessi"},"geo":{"s":"None"},"location":{"s":"Valley of the sun☀️"},"polarity":{"s":"0.0"},"tweet":{"s":"b\"RT @bannerite: Donald Trump's lies have consequences. We're seeing them now | Charlotte Observer #DemForce""},"created_at":{"s":"Mon Aug 07 19:36:40 +0000 2017"},"screen_name":{"s":"JessiAtkins06"},"followers_count":{"s":"19"}}
```

I created the hive table like so:

```
create external table table1 (
    > id struct<s:string>,
    > sentiment struct<s:string>,
    > subjectivity struct<s:string>,
    > username struct<s:string>,
    > geo struct<s:string>,
    > location struct<s:string>,
    > polarity struct<s:string>,
    > tweet struct<s:string>,
    > created_at struct<s:string>,
    > screen_name struct<s:string>,
    > followers_count struct<s:string>)
    > ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
    > STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

And then loaded the data from the json file using the usual "load data inpath..." formula.

I need to extract hashtags from the "tweet" field, but when I try to do a regular expression to search for hashtags, I get an error:

```
hive> select regexp_extract(lower(tweet), '/\B#\w*[a-zA-Z]+\w*/',0) as patterns
    > from table1
    > limit 10;
FAILED: NullPointerException null
```

I'm wondering if this is because of the struct format of the fields. I could have exported the dynamo file as csv, but the tweets have many commas in them. The same error happens whether the int field is set to 0, 1, or 2.

I'm trying to determine what value in the field is null and I'm really not sure - I tried a similar command on a table that was made up of string-type fields and it worked. I've looked at the "What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?" thread but still have no idea; any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace that led to the NullPointerException? it's usually in a separate hivelogs folder

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a stack trace, but I uploaded hive.log to http://www.vaughn-s.net/hadoop/hive.log

Comment: I don't see NullPointerException anywhere in that log...

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure where to find a stack trace, especially on amazon emr. I wish I could be of greater assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I retraced your steps and also received the NullPointerException.

Next, I ran a simpler query and got this:

```
select tweet from table1;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
```

It seems that in your example input data, you have an extra `"` (after `#DemForce`) which breaks the json deserialization.

You can either add `\` before each `"` in the tweet so that the `"` would be treated as text.

If you export as csv, you must remove all commas from the content beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, it's appreciated. Is there a better way to deal with the quote marks?

If I import the dynamodb as csv instead, is there a way to deal with all of the commas in the tweets?

Comment: Great, that helps a lot! Thanks again